# MySQL 8 packages not found after adding repository

Tags: apt, mysql, 18.10

I added the official MySQL repository just as instructed [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/),
it works just fine in Ubuntu 18.04 , and the mysql-server version 8 is available, but for some reason in 18.10 it doesn't work, I can't seem to find MySQL version 8 packages, please help.

Comment: How did you added repository? Have you ran `sudo apt update` after that? Any errors shown? What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`?

Comment: the output  of cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list :
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ cosmic mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ cosmic mysql-8.0
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ cosmic mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ cosmic mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ cosmic mysql-8.0

Comment: Repository information looks ok. Have you ran `sudo apt update` and then tried installation?

Comment: yes i did many times , the problem is only with mysql version 8 packages not being available workbench community edition version 8 is available and installed successfully

Answer (score 2):

I do confirm this issue on Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic) whereas on 18.04 and 19.10, it's working fine. It seems that the package information is missing from [MySQL's repository information for Cosmic](http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/mysql-8.0/binary-amd64/Packages). But it should look like something like [this](http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/disco/mysql-8.0/binary-amd64/Packages).

So, clearly it's the issue from MySQL repository. You could either wait until it is corrected or download relevant packages from [pool](http://repo.mysql.com/apt/pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/) and install them.

Comment: Is there any documentation on what pool is? (Even better: Is there documentation somewhere on how to navigate repo.mysql.com in general, and what the purpose of each directory is, and who updates these files, and how they generated the files?)

Comment: @DavidWiniecki You might be interested in knowing more about [Debian Repository Format](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format) :)