# Can't install MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: mysql, 19.04

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 and downloaded version 8.13 of MySQL APT config and ran these commands

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

I checked `mysql.list` using

```
vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
```

and found version 8 is configured. And then I ran

```
apt install mysql-server
apt-cache show mysql-server
apt update
```

But still I can't install MySQL 8. APT is still pointing to 5.7.

Comment: first apt-get update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume something got messed up with the apt internals and waiting 24 hours allowed everything clear and rebase itself. Where as before most - but not all - of the apt and ubuntu tools showed that mysql-8.0 was the default after doing the **dpkg -i mysql-8.13** (not the actual package name).

I went back today (not quite 24 hours later) and now attempting to do the install for mysql-server shows what I expect to see:

```
root@mrserver:~# apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmecab2 mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-client mysql-common mysql-community-client mysql-community-client-core mysql-community-server mysql-community-server-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmecab2 mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-client mysql-common mysql-community-client mysql-community-client-core mysql-community-server mysql-community-server-core mysql-server
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 23.1 MB/30.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 295 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score 1):

APT maintains a list of packages in ***/var/lib/apt/lists*** that would be downloaded when asked. The files in the above said folder are generally **InRelease** files or **Release** files which contains such information. According to [DebianRepository/Format - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format):

> To download packages from a repository apt would download a **InRelease** or **Release** file from the **$ARCHIVE_ROOT/dists/$DISTRIBUTION** directory.
>
> **InRelease** files are signed in-line while **Release** files should have an accompanying **Release.gpg** file.
>
> The **Release** file lists the index files for the **distribution** and their hashes (the index file listed are relative to **Release** file location).
>
> To download index of the main component apt would scan the Release file for hashes of files in the main directory. eg. *http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/main/binary-i386/Packages.bz2* which would be listed in *http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/main/Release* as *binary-i386/Packages.bz2*

For MySQL, it seems the [**InRelease** file for Disco](http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease) although contains the required details **but** the [package information in ***/mysql-8.0/binary-amd64/***](http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/disco/mysql-8.0/binary-amd64/Packages) is empty. This is the main cause of the underlying issue. This ain't the first time MySQL did such thing. An exactly [similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/1138554/816190) happened 6 months ago, i.e. April 2019.

After looking the situation, it seems MySQL *thinks* that non-LTS releases are supported for 6 months *or* expects the users to upgrade to the latest non-LTS as soon as possible. I won't be surprised if they remove package information of 19.10 in April 2020.

However, MySQL version can still be downloaded and installed *but* by using either Bionic's (18.04) or Eoan's (19.10) repository information. It would install MySQL version 8.0 without breaking the system. I assume that you have already installed mysql-apt-config deb package which create **mysql.list**

- If 18.04's repository information is to be used

  ```
    sudo sed -i 's/disco/bionic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
  ```
- If 19.10's repository information is to be used

  ```
    sudo sed -i 's/disco/eoan/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
  ```

Then finally run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

It's upto you if you want to *keep other release's* repository information. Keeping it won't harm your system as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I fixed this by updating to 19.10 and then the default mySQL installation was v 8.0 anyway.