# 'apt-cache policy' has no candidate to install 'mysql-server' of 8.0.* versions

Tags: apt, mysql, 19.04

I have Ubuntu 19.04 (disco). And I need to install MySQL 8.0.*.

I followed the instructions from the official MySQL site to install version 8.0.*, but the version never appeared on the list of installation candidates.

Official [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/) contains:

> Adding the MySQL APT Repository
>
> First, add the MySQL APT repository to your system's software
>   repository list. Follow these steps:
>
> ```
> Go to the download page for the MySQL APT repository at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/.
>
> Select and download the release package for your Linux distribution.
>
> Install the downloaded release package with the following command, replacing version-specific-package-name with the name of the
> ```
>
> downloaded package (preceded by its path, if you are not running the
>   command inside the folder where the package is):
>
> ```
> shell> sudo dpkg -i /PATH/version-specific-package-name.deb
> ```
>
> For example, for version w.x.y-z of the package, the command is:
>
> shell> sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_w.x.y-z_all.deb
>
> Note that the same package works on all supported Debian and Ubuntu
>   platforms.
>
> During the installation of the package, you will be asked to choose
>   the versions of the MySQL server and other components (for example,
>   the MySQL Workbench) that you want to install. If you are not sure
>   which version to choose, do not change the default options selected
>   for you. You can also choose none if you do not want a particular
>   component to be installed. After making the choices for all
>   components, choose Ok to finish the configuration and installation of
>   the release package.
>
> You can always change your choices for the versions later; see
>   Selecting a Major Release Version for instructions.
>
> Update package information from the MySQL APT repository with the
>   following command (this step is mandatory):
>
> shell> sudo apt-get update
>
> Instead of using the release package, you can also add and configure
>   the MySQL APT repository manually; see Appendix A: Adding and
>   Configuring the MySQL APT Repository Manually for details.

After the steps in the instructions, I have the following as a result of running the `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list` command:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ disco mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ disco mysql-8.0
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ disco mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ disco mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ disco mysql-8.0
```

But as a result of running the sudo apt install mysql-server command, I get the following:

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building a dependency tree Reading status information ... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 libmecab2 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql -server-core-5.7
Suggested packages: mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 libmecab2 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql -server-core-5.7
Updated 0 packages, installed 9 new packages, 0 packages were marked for deletion, and 0 packages were not updated.
Need to download 19.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, the volume of used disk space will increase by 156 MB.
Want to continue? [Y / n]
```

'apt' offers only mysql-*-5.7 version, and there is no version 8.0 at all.

Also, running the sudo apt-cache policy mysql-server command gives me the following:

```
mysql-server:
  Установлен: (отсутствует)
  Кандидат:   5.7.28-0ubuntu0.19.04.2
  Таблица версий:
     5.7.28-0ubuntu0.19.04.2 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/main i386 Packages
     5.7.25-1 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main i386 Packages
```

In the version table, there is not one other than 5.7.*.

At the same time, I have added 'main', 'restricted', 'universe', 'multiuniverse' repositories.

All signs indicate that version 8 should be installed, but it does not appear in the list of candidates for installation. What could be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161786/cant-install-mysql-8-on-ubuntu-19-04)

Comment: Did you forget to run `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 0):

you should run command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config
```

[select the first option here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4aBl.png)

[you can choose the version you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSzmZ.png)

```
sudo apt-get clean all
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

you can install

P.s.

```
mysql-apt-config is broken or not fully installed
```

if you get a similar error

https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb

you can download and install here

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb
```