# When installing ROS I get a package can't be found despite following the right instructions

Tags: 19.10, ros

I followed this link exactly: http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu

I started with setting up my sources.list:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

Then setup my keys:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

Then ensured my Debian package was up to date:

```
sudo apt update
```

This is all worked fine until it came to installation, any of the variants

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

Or

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop
```

Or

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-ros-base
```

All give me the error unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full or it's variants but I don't understand why. When installing these on my other laptop I never ran into any problems and both originally run Windows and are running Ubuntu on a virtual machine.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Sorry I should've specified, Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: I can confirm that this doesn't work. The repository at `packages.ros.org` does not contain a package `ros-melodic-desktop` or any of the others you mention. You can see for yourself:  in `/var/lib/apt/lists/` in any of the `packages.ros.org_`  files, there is no line that starts with `Package` and contains `ros-melodic`. There must be something wrong on the server side.

Comment: @Jos That seems like an answer :)

Comment: @Kulfy It must be something temporary. I can't find any `.deb` file in any of the folders under `http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/`.

Comment: @Jos IIRC deb files are located in pool. The package locations are generally provided in Packages file. It seems [packages file for Bionic](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages) is ok but [that of Eoan](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/eoan/main/binary-amd64/Packages) is incomplete. (Related: [How to see all packages in a package repository? Website or command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210473))

Comment: @Kulfy My turn to say "That seems like an answer" :)

Comment: Ah OK, I am using a company computer and so there are some restrictions, could this be why it worked on my personal laptop but not this one?

Answer (score 5):

The [Packages file for Eoan](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/eoan/main/binary-amd64/Packages) doesn't have entries for the above said packages. On the other hand, those are available in [that of Bionic](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages). The packages seems to have been removed for all new releases since the [Packages file for Disco](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/disco/main/binary-amd64/Packages) also don't have information for those packages. The dependencies in newer releases can't be satisfies without breaking the operating system. This could be a reason for the removal.

Moreover even if you try to use Bionic Beaver's software sources for installing those packages in newer releases, the dependencies won't still get satisfied. If you really need to use those packages, either use Bionic Beaver or compile from [source](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source).

---

#### Related posts:

- [My answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1210485/816190) on [How to see all packages in a package repository? Website or command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1210473/816190)
- [My other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1183560/816190) on [Can't install MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1161786/816190)

Answer (score 1):

ROS Melodic is [only required to support Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023). According to [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/336691/will-any-ros-1-or-2-distribution-run-on-ubuntu-1910/?answer=336708#post-id-336708) on the ROS Answers support forum, there is no ROS distribution intended to run on 19.10.

In general, each ROS release only supports a few operating systems and you will face significant friction if you try to use anything else. Unless you have a strong reason not to, I suggest using your ROS version's primarily targeted OS, which for Melodic is Ubuntu 18.04.