# How to obtain the latest .deb package of Vivalvi browser?

Tags: scripts, downloads, wget, opera, vivaldi

How to download the latest .deb of Vivaldi browser using `wget` generic  command (with the help of wildcards)? Vivaldi can't be downloaded without entering the exact name and number of the latest build. For example,

```
wget https://downloads.vivaldi.com/stable/vivaldi-stable_3.5.2115.81-1_amd64.deb
```

What I want is something easy like in the case of `firefox` and `google-chrome`, where

```
wget -nc -O ${HERE}/FirefoxSetup.tar.bz2 "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-US"
```

and

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

are working very well, downloading the latest versions of these browsers without the need to specify the exact name and build number, unlike in the case of Vivaldi. I want to have a script that downloads this browser(Vivaldi) anytime without my intervention to update/change it.

Comment: Use MATE Software Boutique. Do not invent bicycles.

Comment: I don't want to install anything ,I just want to download the .debs of these browsers.For Vivaldi i even tried to replace this group of numbers, " 3.5.2115.81-1 " with " * " ,to be kind of generic command but it didn't work.Maybe is there another symbol to mask/replace those numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117988/wget-with-wildcards-in-http-downloads

Comment: Vivaldi shows `ERROR 403: Forbidden` when a wildcard is used.

`wget -r --no-parent -A 'vivaldi-stable_*.deb' https://downloads.vivaldi.com/stable/`

There's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian based systems where APT tool is available, you can download deb packages without installing them by replacing `apt-get install` with `apt-get download` in [N0rbert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1303341/816190). However, since you still want to use `wget` and avoid APT, you need to first understand, Vivaldi, doesn't name their latest release like Firefox and Google Chrome do. Firefox and Google Chrome generally makes `latest`/`current` point to the latest release which Vivaldi don't follow. It just adds the version number in the deb package name.

Since, Vivaldi maintains a file known as [Packages](https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/) which contains information about the builds currently available in the repository for a particular architecture (see [How to see all packages in a package repository? Website or command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1210473/816190)). It generally has a stable build and a snapshot. As of now snapshot's information is placed at top. Might confirm later whether the information placement is random or fixed.

A simple bash script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages
ver=$(tac Packages| grep -m1 Version | cut -d " " -f2)
wget https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/pool/main/vivaldi-stable_"$ver"_amd64.deb
rm Packages
```

**Some explanation:**
First downloaded the *Packages* file. Extracted the latest version string and stored in `ver` variable. Since the stable's information is stored at bottom of the file, [`tac`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tac.1.html) was used to reverse the rows. Used [`grep`](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html) to extract the "*version*". And to limit results `-m` flag was used. Since the result is like "*Version: VersionNumber*", used [`cut`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) with `-f` flag to get second field, i.e., *VersionNumber*. Since debs are in /pool, used `wget` and value of `ver` to get the *latest* build from there. Finally removed *Packages* file.

If you're using some other architecture you can use that instead of amd64, for example, i386. I assumed that there was no file with name as *Packages* already existing in the current working directory. You might like to create a new folder specially for this and delete it later from the script itself. Alternatively, you can use `-O` option from `wget`.

Comment: Kulfy ,I owe you the most of my gratitude ,because I loved the pure scripting way of solving this ".deb browser" ache of mine.It works sooooo nice.To vivaldi and as a bonus to opera-stable too.Now could I dare to ask you something more?How to extend your script to opera-developer ,which is on 3rd row(middle row) out of 5 rows in Package file.So cat/tac doesn't work anymore.Tried ed , sed , awk ,but becomes too complicated and exceeds my (in)competence in scripting.

Comment: I think I got it to work: ' #!/bin/bash -x
wget https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages
ver=$(awk '/opera-developer/{c=0};(c!=""&&c++==1)' Packages| grep -m1 Version | cut -d " " -f2)
wget https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/pool/non-free/o/opera-developer/opera-developer_"$ver"_amd64.deb
rm Packages '  .Man I'm struggeling with comment text formatting.

Comment: @msf Instead of `awk` and even `tac`, you can use `grep` and `sed` to make it universal. For example, if you know the placement of information, like `opera-developer` is placed at 3rd position, you can use `grep "Version" Packages | sed '3q;d' | cut -d" " -f2`. Replace `3` with the required number.

Answer (score 1):

OK, let me parse [JSON](https://github.com/ubuntu-mate/ubuntu-mate-welcome-legacy/blob/c46a81eb3e3ed75f5668fbe548ef5e0f94d9c7e3/data/js/applications.json) from [Ubuntu MATE Software Boutique](https://ubuntu-mate.org/features/boutique/) for you.

| **Browser** | **Repository** | **install command** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vivaldi | http://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ | `wget https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/pool/main/vivaldi-stable_3.5.2115.81-1_amd64.deb && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y ./vivaldi-stable_3.5.2115.81-1_amd64.deb` |
| Opera | https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ | `wget https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/pool/non-free/o/opera-stable/opera-stable_73.0.3856.284_amd64.deb && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y ./opera-stable_73.0.3856.284_amd64.deb` |
| Firefox | https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/firefox | `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firefox` |
| Chrome | http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ | `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` |

But this solution is not universal.

More universal solution is to add repositories to the system and then install packages from them:

- Vivaldi

  ```
  cd /tmp
  wget http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/linux_signing_key.pub
  sudo apt-key add linux_signing_key.pub
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable main"
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install vivaldi-stable
  ```
- Opera

  ```
  cd /tmp
  wget https://deb.opera.com/archive.key
  sudo apt-key add archive.key
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free"
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install opera-stable
  ```
- Firefox

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install firefox
  ```
- Chrome

  ```
  cd /tmp
  wget http://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
  sudo apt-key add linux_signing_key.pub
  sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 78BD65473CB3BD13
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
  ```

and as the result all these packages will have automatic updates (by unattended upgrades) or manual updates by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Thank you all.The thing is I don't want to install these browsers ,I download ,unarchive and use them in portable way.Until now it is working very well with firefox and google-chrome .I wanted to experiment also with vivaldi and opera too ,in the same way (using scripts in terminal ) ,but seems imposible with the " Italian composer ".For opera I found this " wget -Oopera.deb 'www.opera.com/download/get/?id=35889&location=360&nothanks=yes&sub=marine' " ,but I don't know from where is this url because if you go to the official page of opera ,you will get another adress of the .deb.

Comment: You can use apt to just download package. Rest of procedure is same as in this answer

Comment: `apt-get download will download the package, but not its dependencies, to the current directory. apt-get -d install will download the given package and all missing dependencies to the system packages directory`

Comment: @N0rbert I managed to make it work combining your and@ LuxZg's  method after importing gpg keys(forgot to do this at the beginning and had constant error message).But to download the deb it needs to type the root pass.