# How do I download the .deb package of Vivaldi browser using wget and wilcards?

Tags: wget, wildcards, vivaldi

How to download the latest .deb of Vivaldi browser using `wget` with the help of wildcards? Vivaldi can't be downloaded without entering the exact name and number of the latest build. For example,

```
wget https://downloads.vivaldi.com/stable/vivaldi-stable_3.5.2115.81-1_amd64.deb
```

I tried to replace the middle segment, containing numbers with the wildcard asterisk (*) but it didn't work.

```
wget https://downloads.vivaldi.com/stable/vivaldi-stable_*_amd64.deb
```

Maybe there are other wildcard symbols, less known, that could do the job.

Comment: Why do you invent new concepts again? The question was comprehensively answered before - https://askubuntu.com/a/1303341/66509. Also you can grab all files from https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/pool/main/ and then find latest.

Comment: None of the answers were what I hoped, because as I said before :I don't want to install this or other browser .The possibility to upgrade the app, is not so important .What I really want is to have in a script a succession of commands that lead to downloading and unpacking the latest .deb of Vivaldi browser ,making it ready to be used,in a portable manner.The essential condition is to have wget to use wildcards or something similar to download AUTOMATICALLY the latest version no matter what build number it has.This works excellently with Frefox and Chrome ,but not with Vivaldi or Opera

Comment: @msf The ideal way to *install* latest version, is to use Vivaldi's repository, which the answer below describes. Why do you want `wget` to retrieve the latest build and why is it *essential*? Unlike Chrome, Vivaldi doesn't name their latest version as `*current*`. You can even adapt the steps in a script replacing `add-apt-repository` command with `echo "deb https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list`. If you want want to download the *latest* deb, you can then use `apt download vivaldi`.

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion , but it gives this error : Error: package vivaldi not found in APT cache!

Comment: I'm NOT installing these browsers ,only download ,unpack in a directory and use them PORTABLE .No install. Atall. Never. Ever.I install only essential stuff .Browsers ,excepting the default one already included in the distro,are not essential.So I don't install them.inline But I like to download and test them to see what progress they have made.Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Wildcards in `wget` is unrealistic as the tool will not know the name of every file in a given directory on the web server. If your goal is to have an easy way to keep the Vivaldi browser up to date, then you can use their repository. Here's how to set it up:

1. Import the public key (to allow for verification of the APT repository)

   ```
   wget -qO- https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Add the repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable main'
   ```
3. Install Vivaldi

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install vivaldi-stable
   ```

Now every time your system does an `apt update`, Vivaldi will be included in the check.

Source: [Manual setup of the Vivaldi Linux repositories | Vivaldi Browser Help](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/install-update/manual-setup-vivaldi-linux-repositories/)