# How to add mysql-8.0 repository from archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-8.0/

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql

Official repo for MySQL8 https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ not working. 
How to add `archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-8.0/` to source list for Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic for setup MySQL8?

I'm trying to add next list to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`

```
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main  bionic main
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main bionic main
```

but it's not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161786/cant-install-mysql-8-on-ubuntu-19-04) I'd suggest to add MySQL's repository for other release instead of Ubuntu's main repository of some other release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method:

```
wget https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb
```

Text window will appear:

- Select Xenial as most recent and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Select `MySQL Server & Cluster (Currently selected: mysql-5.7)` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Select `mysql-8.0 preview` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Select `OK` and press

But you could get the following errors during `sudo apt update`:

```
Err:3 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 8C718D3B5072E1F5 MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
Reading package lists... Done               
W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 8C718D3B5072E1F5 MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

To get rid of those errors, remove newly added repository file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
```

So try the second method.

The second method if the first did not go:

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` should look like this for that:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

**If your server is used for learning and testing purposes, OS dependencies issues and system breaking are accessible, then you could try to add the next to your `sources.list`**:

```
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted
```

Then `sudo apt update && sudo apt install mysql-server-8.0`

During `mysql-server-8.0` package installation copy installed packages information somewhere to have the ability to remove them and install supported versions instead after eoan's repository commenting. It could remove other packages, required for stable system processing. So be prepared to recover or reinstall your system.

After mysql-server installation

- Comment out `eoan` repository record
- `sudo apt clean && sudo apt update`

To roll back to normal configuration:

- `sudo apt purge mysql-server-8.0 && sudo apt autoremove`
- Comment or remove `eoan` record in `sources.list`
- `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: in this case, suggests installing mysql 5.7, not mysql 8

Comment: `sudo apt install mysql-server-8.0`

Comment: now say, that package `mysql-server-8.0` not found

Comment: Yes, sorry. Just downloaded packages list for Bionic and it shows only 5.7 there. 8.0 available in `eoan`.

Comment: It's a hack and not recommended if you do not want to have troubles with dependencies, but you could try to enable `eoan` main for a moment to try to install 8.0. What are your purpose to use 8.0 and what is importance of your server. Is it for testing and learning or for production?
`deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted`

Comment: It's for testing new release of software

Comment: Thanks, It's working)

Comment: @VitaliyLamashevskiy Please don't prepend "Accepted" in front of question title. Rather click on grey ✔ on the left of the answer which helped you.

Comment: @Gryu In my understanding users generally install MySQL on a machine which is deployed on server side. Adding main repositories of some other release and then upgrading the OS might break the system horribly. Related: [Is editing sources.list a good idea?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061450/is-editing-sources-list-a-good-idea)

Comment: @Kulfy tried adding repository as you suggested under a question and it failed to update.

Comment: @Gryu I didn't get any error. The expired key error is generally a temporary server side error. I assume that it was fixed in the mean time.